# Rails app can't upload files that use gem jquery_mobile_rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-mobile

### GemFile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery_mobile_rails'
```

### application.js:

```
//= require jquery.mobile
```

### html:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/home/test" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <br>
  <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
    <input id="test" name="test" type="file">
  </div>
  <div class="ui-btn ui-input-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
    <input type="submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

### controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:test]

  def index

  end

  def test

    binding.pry

  end

end
```

---

After the current selection file is submitted, no params[:test] in the params. But when I get rid of "//= require jquery.mobile",params[:test] in the params.
I do not know you have not encountered, is how to solve?

Comment: are there any errors in javascript console? can you add rails logs of get/post requests? without additional information it will be very hard for you to get any help.

Comment: There are no errors in javascript console.

`Started POST "/home/test" for ::1 at 2016-07-29 09:04:39 +0800

Processing by HomeController#test as HTML


From: xxx/xxx/app/controllers/home_controller.rb @ line 9 HomeController#test:


     8: def test

 =>  9:   binding.pry

    10: end


[1] pry(#<HomeController>)> params

=> {"controller"=>"home", "action"=>"test"}

[2] pry(#<HomeController>)> exit

  Rendered home/test.html.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms)
  
Completed 200 OK in 20449ms (Views: 48.1ms)`